# Debugging a BigQuery csv load failure

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a csv file and I get the following error which I'm not quite sure how to follow:

> CSV table references column position 18, but line starting at position:1057924150 contains only 18 columns.

What would be the best way to debug this? I tried opening this in python and doing something like:

```
file_data[1057924150 - 20 : 1057924150 + 20]
```

But it seems like that doesn't get me to the correct position. What's the simplest way to see what the line is that BQ is giving an error on (or at least referencing in its error message)?)

Comment: Can you provide a command that you are using to load a file? Additionally, an example of your source file will be really helpful to start recreating the scenario. Does your first row contain the headers? Do you have any lines containing “\” at the end?

Comment: @David542, could you please tell me how do you managed to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the records based on the count of delimiter where it is not meeting required number of columns.

Let's assume your file and BQ table has a total of 20 columns but one of the record in the file has only 18 columns, which will fail the job. We can search for such records using awk. (assuming your file is in cloud shell).

```
awk -F',' 'NF==18'  file.csv
```

If your file is large and there is a possibility of more erroneous records then write the records to a file as below and then do your analysis:

```
awk -F',' 'NF==18'  file.csv >> erroneousfile.csv
```